# warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double x,y;
    printf("Enter a double: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("Enter another double:");
    scanf("%lf", &y);
    int *ptr_one;
    int *ptr_two;
    ptr_one = &x;
    ptr_two = &x;
    int *ptr_three;
    ptr_three = &y;
    printf("The Address of ptr_one: %p \n", ptr_one);
    printf("The Address of ptr_two: %p \n", ptr_two);
    printf("The Address of ptr_three: %p", ptr_three);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is every time I try to submit this code this message shows up:

> assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

I thought the `math.h` might fix it but negative. Please need help fixing it.

Comment: GCC compiler gives sufficient information regarding the warning.

`4.c:14:12: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int *' from 'double *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   ptr_one = &x;`

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
ptr_one = &x;
ptr_two = &x;
ptr_three = &y;
```

`ptr_one`, `ptr_two` and `ptr_three` are `int*`s and `&x` and `&y` are `double*`s. You are trying to assign an `int*` with a `double*`. Hence the warning.

Fix it by changing the types of the pointers to `double*` instead of `int*`, i.e, change the following lines

```
int *ptr_one;
int *ptr_two;
int *ptr_three;
```

to

```
double *ptr_one;
double *ptr_two;
double *ptr_three;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in these assignment -

```
ptr_one = &x;     //ptr_one is an int * and &x is double *(assigning int * with double *)
ptr_two = &x;     //ptr_two is an int * and &x is double *
...
ptr_three = &y;   // similar reason
```

Declare `ptr_one` ans `ptr_two` as double pointer (double as data type)-

```
double *ptr_one;
double *ptr_two;
double *ptr_three;
```

An why would `math.h` will help you in this matter ?

Answer (score -1):

Below changes should do

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double x,y;
    printf("Enter a double: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("Enter another double:");
    scanf("%lf", &y);
    double *ptr_one; // HERE
    double *ptr_two; // HERE
    ptr_one = &x;
    ptr_two = &x;
    double *ptr_three; // HERE
    ptr_three = &y;
    printf("The Address of ptr_one: %p \n", (void *)ptr_one); // HERE
    printf("The Address of ptr_two: %p \n", (void *)ptr_two); // HERE
    printf("The Address of ptr_three: %p", (void *) ptr_three); // HERE

    return 0;
}
```