# int pointer to access string elements works to some extent but showing warning.Can you explain about this warning?

Tags: c

I have declared string and pointer ptr of int type.
But to access char type through pointer we use char pointer.
But here it is working properly,only giving warning.
I have written code in Codeblocks.

> Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer- types]

```
 char name[]="Welcome";
 int *ptr;
 ptr=name;
 int i=0;
 while(name[i]!='\0') {
 printf("%c",*(ptr+i));
 i++;
 }
```

Comment: Whats the output?

Comment: What about the warning is unclear? What do you expect the code to do? What does your C textbook say? Sidenote: you can't learn C by trial&error and obscure online tutorials or youtube videos. As a beginner treat warnings like errors.

Comment: @Grantly: asking for the output of undefined behaviour is completely pointless.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666219/warning-assignment-from-incompatible-pointer-type-enabled-by-default

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for confirming the UB, but I just wanted to prompt the OP that what he means by "works", is not true.  The output is "Wo...", which is a great big hint that its not working as he expects.  And it could crash and burn harshly...

Comment: @Grantly: I f it was for me, UB should delete the source code automatically so the user has to write it correctly. Nayway, it would have been better to make clear from the start it is UB and any apperance the code is working is just unfortunate(!) coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behaviour, the fact that it "works" means nothing.

You are mixing types here and that's what the compiler is warning you. The
problem here is this:

```
ptr = name;
```

because you are assigning a `char` pointer to a `int` pointer, they are
incompatible because `char` and `int` have different sizes and this will be a
problem when accessing memory through the `int` pointer.

When you do this:

```
printf("%c", *(ptr+i));
```

you eventually accessing memory out of bounds. `ptr + i` is pointer arithmetic,
that means that the compiler takes the size into account. When the compiler
calculates the offset for the expression `ptr + i`, it calculates the offset by doing `i * sizeof(int)`.
Depending on the length of the string, this offset will be larger than limit of the `name` array. So it will
dereference a pointer past the bounds of the memory, and this yields undefined behaviour.

So the code is just simply wrong, like I said, the fact that it "works" means
nothing. The code could have ended with a segfault or erasing your hard drive.

Comment: Or demons coming out of your nose.

Comment: @N00byEdge yes, this happens to me all the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
int main()
{
    char name[]="Welcome";

    char *ptr;

    ptr=(char*)name;

    int i=0;

    while(name[i]!='\0') {

        printf("%c \n",*(ptr+i));

        i++;

    }

    return 0;

}
```